# Single-word for Jagirdar

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single, English word for Jagirdar. Here is [Britannica description](https://www.britannica.com/topic/jagirdar-system).

> Jāgīrdār system, form of land tenancy developed in India during the
>   time of Muslim rule (beginning in the early 13th century) in which the
>   collection of the revenues of an estate and the power of governing it
>   were bestowed on an official of the state. The term was derived by
>   combining two Persian words: jāgīr (“holding land”) and dār
>   (“official”).

I was thinking Landlord, but landlord owns land.

Jagirdar is the custodian of land who collects taxes from the land's tenants and gives a percentage to the King (last King was British Raj in India).

Farmer may yield 12 bags of rice. Jagirdar takes 6 bags in taxes. Of those 6 bags, 2 go to the King.

Comment: As the quotation within the question makes clear, the Encyclopaedia Britannica leaves the term untranslated. Doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: There doesn't _have_ to be an English word for something that doesn't have an exact equivalent in English-speaking cultures.

Comment: @KateBunting I am writing a novel with English words only. Please guide.

Comment: Yes, but if your novel is about India it's perfectly acceptable to use the local word, either explaining the meaning the first time you use it or adding an explanatory note. For example, many stories about France written in English use the French word _concierge_ for the resident caretaker/doorkeeper of an apartment building.

Comment: @KateBunting Ok, then I shall use the work Jagirdar then

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagir) says "A jagir ... was a type of feudal land grant in the Indian subcontinent at the foundation of its Jagirdar system."  So probably if you want to translate terms related to jagirdar, you should use the corresponding terms related to [feudalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feudalism).

Comment: As the quotation says, the system in question is **a** type of feudalism, i.e. one specific type of feudalism. The OP seems to be interested in the terminology that would be specific to that particular type.